# What is a KVM and why is it useful?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kvm

I understand that a KVM [(Kernel-based Virtual Machine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) is a Linux virtualization solution for machines with special hardware.

What I don't understand what this allows. What problems can you solve with a KVM? Where, when and why is it used?

Comment: Its allow to run a system [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine); see the linked wikipage...

Comment: Can this be migrated to Super User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/28437/kernel-based-virtual-machine-kvm):-

> KVM is a type of hypervisor that enables, emulates and provides for
>   the creation of virtual machines on operating systems. These machines
>   are built on top of the Linux kernel, using operating systems such as
>   Linux, Ubuntu and Fedora. KVM can be installed on all x86 processors
>   and provide separate instruction set extensions for Intel and AMD
>   processors.

Comment: @huitlarc:- Have a look at the difference between Virtualbox and KVM here:- http://virtualization.findthebest.com/saved_compare/Xen-vs-KVM-vs-VirtualBox-Comparison-of-Open-Source-Virtualization-Software

Comment: Also check this:- http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_haswell_virtualization&num=1